# Double min value in an Inductive type tree Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have an inductive type tree defined as follow:

```
type 'a tree1 = Leaf of 'a
           |Branch of 'a tree1 * 'a tree1
```

I want to have a function that takes in this tree as an input, finds a min value in this tree, doubles it (let's call the result as a) and then reproduces another tree of the same type which all of its leaves are replaced by a.

I have a couple of functions to help me do this:

```
let rec findmin (mytree: int tree1) : int  = match mytree with
|Leaf a -> a
|Branch(Leaf x, Leaf y) -> min x y
|Branch(left, right) -> min (findmin left) (findmin right)  

let rec repdoublemin (mytree: int tree1) : int tree1 = match mytree with
|Leaf a -> Leaf (2*a)
|Branch(Leaf x, Leaf y) -> let result = 2 * findmin (Branch(Leaf x, Leaf y)) 
 in Branch (Leaf result, Leaf result)
|Branch(left,right) -> Branch(repdoublemin left, repdoublemin right)
```

My result is not what I expected.

```
repdoublemin Branch (Leaf 5, Branch (Leaf 3, Leaf 10));;
- : int tree1 = Branch (Leaf 10, Branch (Leaf 6, Leaf 6))
```

and I am supposed to get :

```
- : int tree1 = Branch (Leaf 6, Branch (Leaf 6, Leaf 6))
```

Comment: @Lhooq Any thought?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: @melpomene I did not ask to clarify the error message. I asked suggestions to fix the algorithm.

Comment: May I ask why I have 1 downvote on my post?

Comment: min (findmin left, findmin right)  ... this is the way to invoke a function with 2 arguments with C-like syntax :) not ocaml one ...

Comment: @PierreG. I fixed that. I don't know how to replace each value of my tree with a new value.

Comment: you should update your text as, now, the error is different.

Comment: @PierreG. Updated

Comment: I would recommend to take a paper and draw what you want to achieve and think about how you go through the tree.

Comment: it compiles with a minor fix.

Comment: @PierreG. I drew out my tree but my problem is I cannot wrap my head aroung this tree type.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write a helper function

```
replace_all_values : 'a -> 'b tree1 -> 'a tree1
```

Comment: Do you think my findmin function works to find the minimum value of the input tree?

Comment: Should I add an another case after Leaf a? Like Branch(leaf x, leaf y) -> min x y?

Comment: now that `findmin` works well, proceed with the suggestion from melpomene.